# C# Not able to insert records into my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, insert

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString);
cnn.Open();

cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Participant (ParticipantId, LastName, FirstName, Country, Rank, Gender, IACMember) 
                       VALUES (@ParticipantId, @LastName, @FirstName, @Country, @Rank, @Gender, @IACMember)", cnn);

// cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParticipantId", notnull);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cbHomeCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rank", txtRank.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IACMember", chkMember.Checked);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cnn.Close();
```

I keep getting the error message:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@ParticipantId".' "

I have tried this multiple ways and have been trying to figure this out for a week now. I'm not understanding what is the bug in my code.

Updated version below:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString);
cnn.Open();

cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Participant (LastName, FirstName, Country, Rank, Gender, IACMember) 
                       VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @Country, @Rank, @Gender, @IACMember)", cnn);

//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParticipantId", );    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cbHomeCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rank", txtRank.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IACMember", chkMember.Checked);

int nextKey;

cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(ParticipantId) FROM Participant", cnn);
nextKey = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1;
// cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove "notnull" I know it doesn't exist

Comment: Well, you are passing `@ParticipantId` as a parameter in the query but then you are not providing it (for some reason you commented it out?)

Comment: because i get this error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@ParticipantId nvarchar(4000),@LastName nvarchar(8),@FirstName ' expects the parameter '@ParticipantId', which was not supplied.'"

Comment: If `ParticipantId` is the PK, just omit it and let the DB supply it

Comment: The value in the second parameter is the one I think is the problem. I need to go to the next record, I have tried @paraticipantId, + 1) but that didn't work

Comment: Put proper value and uncomment `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParticipantId"...`

Comment: What would the proper value be? it's a varchar15, yet it says something about needing an integer

Comment: What is the data type of that column in database? Is it primary key column? Is it identity column in database table?

Comment: Like @Plutonix says, take `ParticipantId` and `@ParticipantId` out of your sql statement, since it looks like a PrimaryKey field.  You aren't supplying a value for it anyway.

Comment: i did and i get the message saying "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.'"

Comment: Check your other fields to make sure they are not too large for the column.  Can you post the Table def?

Comment: Rank is a string?  Gender?

Comment: @Brad.post complete code. then it would be easy to provide solution instead of trial and error method.

Comment: ParticipantId (int, not null)
LastName (nvarchar(150, not null)
FirstName (nvarchar(150, not null)
Country (nvarchar(150, not null)
Rank (smallint, null)
Gender (nvarchar(1), not null)
IACMember (bit, not null) 
SponsorId (int, null)

Comment: post the complete code of just that method??

Comment: Rank = smallint, but you are passing text: txtRank.Text.  Don't do that.  Is your txtGender.Text one letter?

Comment: Yes gender is just one character

Comment: Why isn't ParticipantId an Identity field?  Or is it?

Comment: yes it is, i just don't know what to do with it at this point

Comment: have ou defined ParticipantId with auto increment?

Comment: You don't include it in your query.  Like it's been said a couple times now, take it out.

Comment: Yes i did lars. i will post an updated code that gets no errors, but still doesn't add records

Comment: Try `int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and examine the value of count.  If it's one, then it worked.

Comment: tried, no errors, but no records inserted

Comment: I didn't say anything about errors.  What was the returned value?

Comment: Sorry, read that wrong. I returned -1 in my message box

Comment: What are you doing?  ExecuteScalar is for returning one row one column.  Again, try `int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and see what value count is after it runs.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing. Because you can't return a value in the way you tell me to, it does nothing with the line of code you suggest me to use. I put it in a MB and it returned -1. There is no other way to return the value of that? If so enlighten me please, because I'm mentally retarded.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: If you read the document for [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), it tells you "Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and *returns the number of rows affected*."  It's a function.  If the value it gives you is zero, then the insert sql didn't work.  If it's greater than zero, than it worked.  It's that simple.  If it works but you don't see the results in the database, you are probably looking at the wrong database.

Answer (score 1):

if the column ParticipantId is marked as Identity Then You Should Not Try To Manually Insert data in it , sql server will populate it depending on last used ParticipantId , therefore u should remove the column from the insert statement and remove the id parameter .

if its just a Primary Key then u will need to manually insert unique value for each row .

the error mentioned above is because of the commented line which was supposed to provide a value for ParticipantId parameter

Comment: so could i do this to generate a unique id? cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(ParticipantId) FROM Participant", cnn);
nextKey = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() + 1;

Comment: i think letting the database engine handle the id sequence will be much easier , just mark the column as identity